# Datomic: on a Peer, does Connection.db() read your writes after Connection.transact()

Tags: consistency, datomic

Consider the following operations, occuring in a Datomic Peer:

```
(require '[datomic.api :as d])

(let [;; running a transaction and awaiting completion
      tx-res @(d/transact-async conn tx-data)
      ;; reading the current database value
      db1 (d/db conn)]
  ,,,)
```

In the consistency model of Datomic, can I expect the changes made by `tx-res` to be visible in `db1`?

(I know about both `:db-after` `(d/sync conn t)`, but it can be practical to rely on reading your writes on the Connection, e.g for doing successive writes on a connection without having to carry along database values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Val,

Yes, `db1` would include the changes made in the transaction. However, this approach is considered bad practice, as you're reading the same value twice (`tx-res` already has the value of the resulting db). Further, you're not guaranteed that `db1` is the *same* database value as the `:db-after` from the transaction.

We highly recommend using the `:db-after` as returned from the transaction for a subsequent read.

-Marshall

Comment: Thansk @Marshall. Bad practice or not, I actually need to know what the specified behaviour is, since the goal is to get the Datomock library to match Datomic's behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Can not be sure about a datomic implementation without seeing code

But from what I understand about the datomic cache

as tx was derefed, "this" jvm get back "live index", so, `(>= (d/basis-t (d/db conn)) (d/basis-t db-after))`. 
`>` may occur in case of 2 concurrent transactions,

- thread 1 transact
- thread 2 transact
- !transactor do 1, then 2!
- thread 2 deref
- thread 1 deref
- thread 1 asks for db.